# Row space and kernel in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am preparing a "dictionary" that translates between the "language of matrices" and the "language of linear transformations" in linear algebra. The dictionary looks more or less like this:

Language of matrices $\quad\quad\quad$ Language of linear transformations

$m\times n$ matrix $A$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$

$i$-th column $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ image of $e_i$ under $f$

column space $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ image of $f$

row space $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ ?

kernel $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$  kernel

columns are LI $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$  f is one-to-one

rows are LI $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$  f is onto

product $A_2 A_1$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ composition $f_2 \circ f_1$

transpose $A^T$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ ?

And so on.

As you can see, I'm missing a "translation" of the notions of row space of a matrix and transpose of a matrix. Do these notions have a simple equivalent in the language of linear transformations?

Answer (score 0):

The transpose becomes the adjoint. Note though, that to define the adjoint you need an inner product on your vector space (and if you have more than one inner product, you have more than one adjoint, see my remarks below).

The row space of a matrix is the image of the adjoint of the linear transformation.

Remarks: If we use $(x,y)$ to denote the dot product, then the reason transpose is important is that $(x,Ay)=(A^Tx,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. If $(x,y)$ is any inner product and $(Bx,y)=(x,Ay)$ for all $x$ and $y$, then $B$ is the adjoint of $A$.